# add png image to Dockerfile

Tags: docker

In my python file I have to load an images into pygame from my folder `pictures`

```
left = pygame.image.load('pictures/left.png')
right = pygame.image.load('pictures/right.png')
```

In my Dockerfile I have tried

```
ADD /pictures .
```

But it's not working and it can't seem to find the file even though the image build worked
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First make sure that the file exists in the docker image. Run the container with a shell and see if the file is there (and where)

Comment: Try `ADD /pictures /` which uses an absolute path

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by creating a folder in the Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir pictures
ADD pictures /pictures/
```